# What does the ^ operator do?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I came across this weird `^` operator and I'm unable to understand what it does

The result of a simple usage of this operator would look like:

```
print "2^4 : ", 2^2
print "4^2 : ", 4^2
print "5^10: ", 5^10
print "10^5: ", 10^5
#2^4 :  0
#4^2 :  6
#5^10:  15
#10^5:  15
```

What is meant by this operator and what does it specifically do?

Comment: [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR)

Comment: Can we re-open please? In Python `^` doesn't have to be XOR. It's easy to override `__xor__`, and an answer explaining that for integer types it has a built-in definition for logical XOR, but that it can be easily changed, would actually be good here.

Comment: @EMS An answer doing so would as well fit into the duplicated question - and actually exists already.

Comment: I added my answer to the duplicated question. The answer over there that mentioned `__xor__` was not useful for someone new to Python. I'm fine leaving this one closed.

Comment: Tip for the future: if you want help on an operator -- or other bits of syntax, really -- you can add quotes and pass it to `help`, e.g. `help("^")` or `help("~")` or `help("def")`.  Even if the description doesn't give you as much information as you want, at least it'll give you a phrase that's easier to google.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`^` is bitwise XOR (exclusive or) operator.

```
>>> 0b010 ^ 0b110
4
>>> bin(0b010 ^ 0b110)
'0b100'
```

See [Binary bitwise operations](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations).